# How to replace existing csv files by exporting new numpy arrays in python

Tags: python, numpy, file, export-to-csv

I want to export numpy arrays as csv files but I may have files with the same names in my folder. So, I want to replace old files with new ones. I am using the following method:

```
arr=np.array([[1., 2.], [2., 1.]])
np.savetxt('arr.csv', arr, delimiter=',')
```

But this method overwrites rows of the existing `arr.csv` file in my folder. Is there a way to completely replace the old file?
I do appreciate any help in advance.

Comment: What is the difference? The file will be overwritten, no?

Comment: Dear @Corralien, the difference is that my previous csv file may have `10` rows. Then new one may have only `8` rows. this method will rewrite the first `8` rows of old one and two last rows will remain there. I I could replace the file, then the problem of that two extra rows will be solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`np.savetxt` (`numpy=='1.20.3'`) overwrites the whole file:

```
arr = np.random.random((3, 2))
np.savetxt('arr.csv', arr, delimiter=',')
```

```
>>> %cat arr.csv
2.123431629646361785e-01,6.914800473216878851e-01
9.544549349895192769e-01,6.749508363116073495e-01
2.238126343800779239e-01,3.919697864527211806e-01
```

```
arr = np.random.random((1, 2))
np.savetxt('arr.csv', arr, delimiter=',')
```

```
>>> %cat arr.csv
4.355318781801621464e-01,4.574856378543381563e-01
```